# How to add numbers in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I am taking a course for Python, and essentially there's this code:

```
num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
num2 = input("Enter another number: ")
result = num1 + num2

print(result)
```

which is supposed to take `num1` and `num2` and add them together, but instead of adding, the program concatenates the result. So for example if `num1 = 5` and `num2 = 9`, the result would be 59 and not 14.

Comment: that's because the `+` operator concatenates strings

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers

Comment: When we use `+` with string python concatenates the strings SO first convert `num1` & `num2` into `int`, Input function of Python take input as a String.

Comment: Do you take a course for Python 2? Don't do that. Python 2 has already reached end of life. Switch to Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do `int(num1) + int(num2)` because `num1` and `num2` are strings.

Note that `"foo" + "bar"` returns `"foobar"`, since `+` used on strings will concatenate them.